# How to upload and download files from server folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating ASP.net MVC5 web application, I want to allow user to upload file to server folder and save the path in database. 
also download the uploaded file from server to his pc .

- upload file ->
  cshtml:

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.attached, new { type = "file" })

create action:

```
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "op_id,op_name,op_typeid,op_date,budget,op_statusid,sup_id,order_no,order_typeid,attached,notes")] operation operation , HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                      file = Request.Files[0];
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    { var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                        bool folder_exists3 = Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + file.FileName));
                        if (!folder_exists3)
                        {
                           file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/"), fileName));
                        }

                    }
                }
                    db.operations.Add(operation);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

- download file ->
  cshtml:

  @Html.ActionLink("operations", "GetFile", new {name=item.attached })

action:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public FileResult GetFile(string name)
        {
            var FileVirtualPath = "c:/uploads/" + name;
            return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));

        }
```

it saves the file name on database but doesn't save file to server folder , so it cannot download it

any help , please?

Comment: You would have to use a `FileStream` to upload the actual image to the specified path. You would have to do something like this: `using (var fs = new FileStream("Path where file will be uploaded",FileMode.Create){
                                    var buffer = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
                                    file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                }`

Comment: did you add enctype = "multipart/form-data" to form?

Comment: @HienNguyen yes I added  enctype = "multipart/form-data"

Comment: @RahulSharma I don't to read file or save it on database , just save it's path and save it on server folder and vise versa

Comment: @user3019180 I know what you are trying to achieve. The code that I showed you in my comment will upload the file to your server and not your database. If you specify your server path location in the FileStream, you file will be uploaded there. And you could just insert your path to your column in your database, and when you retrieve that value, it will point to your server path where the file is saved. I hope I am being clear here.

Comment: @user3019180 do you set permissions for application to write in this folder c:/uploads/
i prefer you to use cloud cdn for upload and download